# positioning images over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a slider (carousel) and i am successful so far yet but i am stuck at one place
here is my code

the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//rotation speed and timer
var speed = 5000;
var run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);

//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $('.slides li').outerWidth(); 
var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

//move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button
$('.slides li:first').before($('.slides li:last'));

//set the default item to the correct position 
$('.slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

//if user clicked on prev button
$('.prev').click(function() {

    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item            
    $('.slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 1000,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('.slides li:first').before($('.slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('.slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;

});


//if user clicked on next button
$('.next').click(function() {

    //get the right position
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.slides ul').css('left')) - item_width;

    //slide the item
    $('.slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 1000, function () {

        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('.slides li:last').after($('.slides li:first'));                  

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('.slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;

});        

//if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it
$('.slides').hover(

    function() {
        clearInterval(run);
    }, 
    function() {
        run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   
    }
); 

});

   //a simple function to click next link
  //a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin
  function rotate() {
$('.next').click();
   }



   </script>
```

And the css is

```
 <style>
 .carousel {
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
            }

  .slides {
overflow:hidden;
/* fix ie overflow issue */
position:relative;
width:735px;
height:198px;
padding-bottom:13px;
         }

    /* remove the list styles, width : item width * total items */  
    .slides ul {
left:0;
top:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;  
width:3000px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
               }

    /* width of the item, in this case I put 250x250x gif */
    .slides li {
float:left;
list-style:none;
width:735px;
               }

    .slides li img {
padding:0;
                   }

    /* Styling for prev and next buttons */
    .slides ul li.buttons {
display:block;  
position:relative;

    }

    .buttons a {
display:block;
width:22px; 
height:46px;
text-indent:-999em;
float:left;
               }

     a.prev {
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) 0px -100px no-repeat;
            }

    a.prev:hover {
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) -60px -100px no-repeat;
                 }

    a.next {
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) -30px -100px no-repeat;

          }

    a.next:hover {
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) -90px -100px no-repeat;
                 }


    .txt{
float:left;
text-align:left;
position:absolute;
margin-top:26px;
margin-bottom:19px;
}

    .txt h1{
margin-left:34px;
display:inline;
font: "Trebuchet MS", bold, 25px;
color:#003399;


}

    .txt p{
margin-left:34px;
font:Verdana,Reg.,18px;
color:#444;
line-height:23px;
}
    .learn_btn
    {
margin-left:32px;
display:block;
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
width:133px;
height:42px;
margin-bottom:-13px;

    }
    .learn_btn:hover
    {
background:url(Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png) 0 -50px no-repeat;


}

    .slide_pos
    {
padding-left:300px;
margin-bottom:15px;



}
    .slide_pos ul li img
    {
    }
    </style>
```

And HTML is:

```
     <body>

     <div class="carousel">

 <div class="slides"> 


    <ul>

        <li>                
                <span class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
                </span>
                <span class="buttons" style="float:right">
                <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
                </span>
            <span class="txt">



                    <h1>New to Intuit App Center?</h1>
                    <p>Discover the right apps <br/> for QuickBooks</p>
                    <a class="learn_btn" href="#"></a>




            </span>

            <img src="Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/hero-banner1.jpg"  alt="Slide 1"/>


        </li>

        <li>


            <span class="txt">
                    <h1>New to Intuit App Center?</h1>
                    <p>Discover the right apps <br/> for QuickBooks</p>
                    <a class="learn_btn" href="#"></a>                                                




            </span>


            <img src="Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/hero-banner2.jpg" alt="Slide 2"/>

        </li>

        <li>


            <span class="txt">
                    <h1>New to Intuit App Center?</h1>
                    <p>Discover the right apps <br/> for QuickBooks</p>
                    <a class="learn_btn" href="#"></a>                                                




            </span>


            <img src="Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/hero-banner3.jpg" alt="Slide 3"/>

        </li>

        <li>


            <span class="txt">
                    <h1>New to Intuit App Center?</h1>
                    <p>Discover the right apps <br/> for QuickBooks</p>
                    <a class="learn_btn" href="#"></a>                                                




            </span>


            <img src="Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/hero-banner4.jpg" alt="Slide 4"/>

        </li>


    </ul>

</div>

    </div>

    </body>
```

i want my navigation buttons prev and next on left and right side of the sliding images respectively but i am unable to do that...i have tried changing the position to absolute etc but i dont know what to do as it seems to be does not working...these buttons should not slide with the images...plssssssss help me out...thanks

Comment: could you provide full links to the images? or are you working locally?

Comment: working locally....let me edit it for the simplicity...sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You're going to want to use css `z-index` for ensuring they stay above the other images.

Comment: now you can see there are only four images which are sliding....i want those navigation buttons over those sliding images but they should not slide along with them....
here is a link to one of the sliding images, all of the four are of same dimensions
zahms.com/awais/test_p4/Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/hero-banner1.jpg

Here is the link for the navigation image, its a sprite image
http://zahms.com/awais/test_p4/Wireframes_Carousels/sprite/sprite.png

do tell me if something more is required for the solution as i need to solve it in any case...thanks...

Comment: dennmat you rocked buddy....i was tooooooooo fool as this property was not coming in my mind and i sped like 5 hours trying to overcome this problem..... :-(

Answer (score 0):

If I undersand correctly you only want the next and prev buttons on top of everything else and to be fixed so they don't slide with each slide? In which case it isn't so much a jquery or javascript problem but only your CSS. I would try this.

Take them out of the spans and add the class `buttons` to each `<a>` as well as `left` and `right`.

```
.buttons{position:absolute; z-index:999;}
.left{left:20px; bottom:20px;}
.right{right:20px; bottom 20px;}
```

Obviously change the above if you want it you need them in different locations.

You also need to take them out of the `<li>` tag and put them directly in the slider holder container which should have a position of `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make sure that the container surrounding the buttons is styled with `position: relative;`  and that the buttons are both styled with `position: absolute;`. This allows for the buttons inside the container to be `positioned` anywhere inside the `relative` container using styles known as `top`,`bottom`,`left`,`right` followed by a percentage or pixel.

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ9f4/**

-- or --

example:

```
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999; /* to insure the buttons stay above the images at all times */
}
#prev {
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#next {
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```